# Как подключить две библиотеки jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, popover

Проблема в том что на версии jQuery 3.2.1+ вообще не работает ajax.. но работает нужный мне popover, а в версиях 2.2.4 работает стабидьно ajax, все наоборот! как подключить обе библиотеки одновременно и будет ли ето работать?

Comment: Никак, не будет.

Comment: @Igor и как проблему решить? как сделать чтоб и одно и другое работало?

Comment: "на версии jQuery 3.0.0+ вообще не работает ajax" - во всем мире работает, а у Вас  не работает? кхм, кхм

Comment: @Igor может синтаксис изменился? пробую тот же код, на версии 2.2.4 все нормально а на 3.0.0/3.2.1/3.3.1 и других ошибка Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function ... если да то помогите) буду благодарен

Comment: @Igor оооп, установил версию  3.2.0 пашет и popover и ajax) всеравно спасибо, так бы сидел пробовал установить две одновременно)

Comment: Вы скорее всего подключили slim версию jquery, она появилась с 3-й версии и в ней выпилен ajax, в обычной версии он есть

Answer (score 0):

Установил версию 3.2.0 все работает